# Convert from a logical plan to another logical plan in Spark Catalyst

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark Catalyst for representing the query plans for an [openCypher](http://www.opencypher.org/) query engine, [ingraph](http://docs.inf.mit.bme.hu/ingraph/). During the query planning process, I would like to convert from a certain logical plan (`Plan1`) to another logical plan (`Plan2`). (I try to keep the question simple, so I omitted some details here. The project is fully open-source, so if required, I am happy to provide more information on [why this is necessary](https://www.slideshare.net/neo4j/graphconnect-europe-2017-ingraph-live-queries-on-graphs#83).)

The best approach I could find is to use `transformDown` recursively. Here is a small example that converts from `Plan1Node`s to `Plan2Node`s by replacing each `OpA1` instance with `OpA2` and each `OpB1` instance with `OpB2`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Attribute
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.{LeafNode, LogicalPlan, UnaryNode}

trait Plan1Node extends LogicalPlan

case class OpA1() extends LeafNode with Plan1Node {
  override def output: Seq[Attribute] = Seq()
}
case class OpB1(child: Plan1Node) extends UnaryNode with Plan1Node {
  override def output: Seq[Attribute] = Seq()
}

trait Plan2Node extends LogicalPlan

case class OpA2() extends LeafNode with Plan2Node {
  override def output: Seq[Attribute] = Seq()
}
case class OpB2(child: Plan2Node) extends UnaryNode with Plan2Node {
  override def output: Seq[Attribute] = Seq()
}

object Plan1ToPlan2 {
  def transform(plan: Plan1Node): Plan2Node = {
    plan.transformDown {
      case OpA1() => OpA2()
      case OpB1(child) => OpB2(transform(child))
    }
  }.asInstanceOf[Plan2Node]
}
```

This approach does the job. This code:

```
val p1 = OpB1(OpA1())
val p2 = Plan1ToPlan2.transform(p1)
```

Results in:

```
p1: OpB1 = OpB1
+- OpA1

p2: Plan2Node = OpB2
+- OpA2
```

However, using `asInstanceOf[Plan2Node]` is definitely a bad smell in the code. I considered using a [Strategy](https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/a-deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer-with-yin-huai#27) for defining conversion rules, but that class is for converting from physical to logical plans.

Is there a more elegant way to define a transformation between logical plans? Or is using multiple logical plans considered an antipattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question.)

Changing `transformDown` to a simple pattern matching (`match`) and recursive calls solved the type issue:

```
object Plan1ToPlan2 {
  def transform(plan: Plan1Node): Plan2Node = {
    plan match {
      case OpA1() => OpA2()
      case OpB1(child) => OpB2(transform(child))
    }
  }
}
```

This seems a type-safe and (based on my limited understanding of Catalyst) idiomatic solution.